# Node Api Doesn't Respond To Postman or through Browser (No Status Code) But on Terminal It showed no error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, postman, body-parser

I Am  developing  a Node API for employee department model

for which i developed couple of Request Like 'GET PUSH PATCH DELETE' (CRUD Operation)
for both end employee & department

i am developing on my local server
here's my app.js looks like

```
const http=require('http');
const app =require('./app');

const port =process.env.PORT || 3000;

const server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen(port);

console.log('Server Has Been Started');
console.log('localhost:'+port);
```

And On the listner side here's my app.js looks like

```
// Dependency 

const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const morgan =require('morgan');
const bodyParser =require('body-parser');
const mongoose =require('mongoose');


// Importing routes 

const employeeRoutes =require('./api/routes/employee');
const departmentRoutes =require('./api/routes/department');



app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Header Defination to Avoid Corp's

app.use((req, res ,next) =>
{
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");
    res.header(
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
        "Origin,X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Accept,Authorization"
        );
    if (req.method === 'OPTIONS')
    {
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods','PUT,POST,PATCH,DELETE,GET');
        return res.status(200).json({});
    }




});

// Routes for api 
app.use('/employee',employeeRoutes);
app.use('/department',departmentRoutes);


// Error Handling 

app.use((req, res, next) =>
{ 
    const error =new Error('Not Found');
    error.status =404;
    next(error);

});

app.use((error, req, res, next) =>
{ 
    
    res.status(error.status ||500);
    res.json({
        error:{
            message:error.message
        }
    });

});




module.exports = app;
```

in order to send request and receiving response as a json on other end
i developed employee .js and department .js with GET PUSH PATCH DELETE
here's my both file looks like

./api/routes/employee.js

it just showcase script to validate code is working or not

```
const express = require('express');
const router =express.Router();
const mongoose =require('mongoose');
const Employee =require('../models/Employee');

router.get('/',(req, res ,next) => {
    res.status(200).json({
        message:'Handling GET request to ./employees'
    });
});


router.post('/',(req, res ,next) => {
    res.status(201).json({
        message:'Handling POST request to ./employees',
       
    });
});

router.get('/:employeeId',(req, res ,next) =>
{
    const id =req.params.employeeId;
    if (id === 'special'){
        res.status(200).json({
            message: 'You Discovered A speacial ID',
            id:id
        });
    } else
    {
        res.status(200).json({
            message:'You passed an ID'
        });
    }
});

router.patch('/:employeeId',(req, res ,next) =>
{
    res.status(200).json({
        message:'Updated Employees'

    });
});


router.delete('/:employeeId',(req, res ,next) =>
{
    res.status(200).json({
        message:'Deleted  Employee'

    });
});



module.exports =router;
```

../api/routes/department.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router =express.Router();

router.get('/',(req, res ,next) =>{
    res.status(200).json({
        message:'Department fetched'
    });
});

router.post('/',(req, res ,next) =>{
    const department={
        name:req.body.name,
        Id:req.body.Id
    };
    res.status(201).json({
        message:'Department created',
        createdDepartment:department
    });
});

router.get('/:departmentId',(req, res ,next) =>{
    res.status(200).json({
        message:'Department Details',
        departmentId: req.params.departmentId
    });
});

router.delete('/:departmentId',(req, res ,next) =>{
    res.status(200).json({
        message:'Department Deleted',
        departmentId: req.params.departmentId
    });
});

router.patch('/:departmentId',(req, res ,next) =>
{
    res.status(200).json({
        message:'Department Updated',
        departmentId :req.params.departmentId

    });
});



module.exports =router;
```

Now when i try to run this code in as permy coding experience it has no logical error
also on terminal it showed
[terminal o/p](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cdeou.png)

but when i try to run in postman
it just loading not response is coming back
like[postman o/p](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fzqvs.png)

and also on web like
[web o/p](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3f0I.png)

and then onto terminal be like
[terminal after get not respond still server is running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYHcE.png)

i know there is problem with connection but i double check all the possible way like proxy and firewall disabled

also i tried to delter node module and package.json(lock) and reinstalled it nothing of them is working
and when i stop the server postman show socket hangup
[sockethangup postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujBjd.png)
i wanna to know where i am lacking with  meaninf ful answer

Comment: Can you show the output of GET and POST operation?

Comment: @PabloM. No o/p as mean of response it getting back it just loading and loading nothing is serving back or request in I Have uploded pictures of o/p you can figure out from there

Comment: @Ant  No o/p is just loading and loading nothig serving back

Comment: You forgot to call `next()` in your CORS middleware function

Comment: @ChrisG Could You Elaborate It Furthermore In Answers

Comment: You have an `app.use` handler below `// Header Defination to Avoid Corp's` (which I guess is supposed to mean "header lines to allow CORS"). This rule is called for every request, but you just add the headers, then don't do anything further, which is why the request hangs. You need to tell express to go on to the next handler by calling `next()`, the third parameter after `req` and `res`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add next() to pass the request to the next middleware after the CORS section.

```js
// Header Defination to Avoid Corp's

app.use((req, res ,next) =>
{
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");
    res.header(
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
        "Origin,X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Accept,Authorization"
        );
    if (req.method === 'OPTIONS')
    {
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods','PUT,POST,PATCH,DELETE,GET');
        return res.status(200).json({});
    }

  // Pass next middleware
  next();

});
```

Comment: Did you figure this out by yourself? Or did you post this after seeing my comment?

Comment: I did a full test on my PC before answer or your answer.

https://cln.sh/J0W2RZ